# How many rows we can retrieve with a select command?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

A table can consist of 1 billion records so can we fetch all the records or Is there any limit for it. actually i faced this question but i am very mush sure about what i answered like we can retrieve all the records nevertheless they are not satisfied with my answer so can anyone give clarification on this...!
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you want to do with 1 billion rows?

Comment: i have just  taken a scenario  for limit of inserting records so similarly  i want to know the limit for retrieving...!

Comment: You can read them all. But it will probably take some time.

Comment: The client application can stream the rows, so there is really no upper limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no specific limit how many rows SQL can load using `SELECT`.

If you write down `Select * FROM datatable`, then it will attempt to load all the rows, though depending on the size and amount of rows and the accessable source where you get the values from, it can take some time. I've a table that can load 100.000+ rows instantly, because all the rows hold little value to that.

My guess is that you're probably asking this because you want to prevent that it takes too long to load.
If you prefer to use a limited amount of rows, (as example, only the first 100)
Then you can use `SELECT TOP 100 FROM datatable` in your query.

EDIT: According to MSDN, there actually is a limit to the maximum amount of rows a DataTable can hold, which will also be the maximum amount of rows you can retrieve with SELECT:
[image]

Comment: Yeah its very use full nevertheless, i was faced this question so  i said there is no limit but they are not satisfied with my answer because of that i placed a query here.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum records that you can fetch is limited by your RAM, but most of all DBMS do chunk and paginate results